# Babyai conda environment

Tags: python, anaconda, virtualenv

I like to use "Babyai" environment for one of my projects. The link of the "Babyai" GitHub page is here [babyai](https://github.com/mila-iqia/babyai). I follow all the steps for installation. However, I did not understand how could I visualize the babyai environment.

Can anyone please explain the steps?

Thank you.